# Query TFS for permissions

Tags: security, tfs, permissions, user-management

Is there a way to list which users and AD groups have permissions to a folder and all sub folders in a TFS project?

EDIT: We are using TFS 2008

Comment: Nice name you've got there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't the *tf permission* command give you a list, and you can use the /recursive flag to get information on subfolders this way?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft.aspx

Comment: Thanks, using tf permission /server:<servername> <path in TFS> worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What version of TFS are you using?
Not sure about seeing permissions at a specific folder level, but you can certainly see who has access to a particular project or project collection.

In TFS2010, in TFS Administration Console, select the Project Collection you want to look at, then click on "Group Membership" on the General tab. From there, you can drill down to see which TFS or WIndows Users/groups have access to the project collection.

Comment: I've updated the question. Would you know how to do this through the TFS command line utility?